# Unix Socket (e.g. for Docker) with JAX-RS (e.g. with RestEasy)

Tags: java, docker, jax-rs, resteasy, unix-socket

I'm trying to connect to an http endpoint via a Unix socket, namely to Docker on my Mac. E.g. [httpie](https://httpie.org) supports this (after installing an [extension](https://github.com/httpie/httpie-unixsocket)) with a url like `http+unix://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/info`. JAX-RS (namely RestEasy on WildFly) doesn't support this out-of-the box. Is there some extension I have to register or is there simply no such thing?

BTW: I'm aware of [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java) and [spotify:docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) (and some forks), as well as the unix-socket libraries [juds](https://github.com/mcfunley/juds) and [junixsocket](https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket)). This question is about JAX-RS only.